# How to declare JSDoc type for an imported class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jsdoc3

For example, I have

```
// ./command/queue.js
export default class Queue {

};

// ./myclass.js
import CommandQueue from "./command/queue";

export default class MyClass {
    /**
     * @type {CommandQueue} <- ???
     */
    commandQueue = null;
}
```

How to set a type for `commandQueue` property? WebStorm says that `CommandQueue` is an unresolved variable or type. What is a proper syntax?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Zippy nowadays I just use TypeScript but actually I just tested it and such syntax works both in WebStorm and VS Code.